# Create SignedURL of google cloud storage object using Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I need to create a signed URL of an object(uploaded with Google Developer Console) stored in Google Cloud Storage using Node.js.

This is my code:

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud');


// Google Cloud Storage Bucket Name
const BUCKET_NAME = 'testBucketName123';
// Google Developer Console project ID
const PROJECT_ID = 'testProjectName123';
/* Google Developer Console -> API Manager -> Credentials ->
       Add credentials -> Service account -> JSON -> Create */
const KEY_FILENAME = 'testKey.json' // relative path
const SECONDS = 1000; // seconds in milliseconds
const URL_VALID_DURATION = 30 * SECONDS;

var gcs = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: PROJECT_ID,
  keyFilename: KEY_FILENAME
});

var filename ='tasksel.png';
var file = gcs.bucket(BUCKET_NAME).file(filename);

file.getSignedUrl({
  // More documention on options at
  // https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.24.1/storage/file?method=getSignedUrl
  action: 'write',
  expires: Date.now() * URL_VALID_DURATION
}, function (err, url) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("URL");
  console.log("-----");
  console.log(url);
  console.log("-----");
  console.log("PUT to this URL to upload to Google Cloud Storage as " + filename);
});
```

I got output with a URL like this:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/testBucketName123/tasksel.png?GoogleAccessId=keyId@iprojectName.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=NaN&Signature=MmI5cQ3NINpOOP%2Fer02R0LxRZJAHplmstvofDXU139VNmZ0MsxpAOTGg6JUHBr8EztiTdR7cNNltoSb0zpM2DCRK5UpDjlrJ6WriSL2uyDsGWgfdx4M1vS0ussRm9BHAT31tqo0U5cdzgJd5rjakPMV06NUw0YYQn1oAEzE6JwThFfUZa%2FexddP763yDOQDKh5sJxW9go3JNmam%2Bk8qq0wJnVP5GNhl3JGlKW7l5AtimUwaI%2BViasX6LNmvwtoyM4%2Fg6Ebx%2BnI9%2Bk2LxWA3c8MUypeEZj0W8AWv%2BAWjf1bzeCEMTOjxV53bo1SA0zmUGjE6GDVd9PnYomwJ88v2h3Q%3D%3D
```

But I got output when open this URL with browser is:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>
<StringToSign>GET NaN /testBucketName123/tasksel.png</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

What is the actual issue? Any ideas?

Comment: This could actually be a problem with the way the gcloud library forms the signature. It doesn't seem from your code as though there is an opportunity for you to interact with that process in a way which would cause the error. What environment are you running this in? Does the json file truly correspond to the project ID you provide?

Comment: am running this on my local ubuntu machine. and am sure the Service  accont key is valid.

Comment: Is your system clock perhaps out of sync? When constructing the signature, `Date.now()` is used. If the resulting signature, based on your system's call to `Date.now()` was out of sync with the server validating the signature, then it would result in a failure to validate the signature.

Comment: Looks to me like you're going to end up with an astronomically large "expires" since you're multiplying the result of the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Your signedURL contains `expires=NaN`.
Expiry should be an integer. Try

```
Date.now() + URL_VALID_DURATION
```

instead of
<s>Date.now() * URL_VALID_DURATION</s>.